# How to Filter Database Records using Textbox - Radio Buttons - Dropdown and Datepicker using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi guys how can i implement search functionality in my Laravel app?

How to Filter Database Records using Textbox - Radio Buttons - Dropdown and Datepicker using laravel

Comment: you can create events (depending on the element) that will trigger an ajax request to query your database with the parameters given.

Comment: You can create a service or an action which queries database for the required data

Answer (score 0):

You may send your filters with ajax request (or http request, it's up to you) and at server side then you can filter your queries using `when(bool $condition, callback $query)`. Its quite elegant way to creating filter - based queries.

```
$query = Product::query();

$query->when($request->category,function ($q) use ($request){
    $q->where("category",$request->category)
});

$query->when($request->has("min_price"),function ($q) use ($request){
    $q->where("price",">=",$request->min_price)
});

// and other filters...

$result = $query->get();
```